# Why does `$router.replace` skipt the server-side-redering?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I have a page (e.g. `/index`) with a button like

```
<button @click="addItemAndRedirect"> {{ $store.state.items.length }} </button>
```

and the method

```
  methods: {
    addItemAndRedirect () {
      this.$store.dispatch('addItem', {}).then((path) => {
        this.$router.replace({ path: path })
      })
    }
```

The target page looks something like

```
export default {
  asyncData (context) {
    console.warn('asyncData')
  },
  fetch () {
    console.warn('fetch')
  },
  fetchOnServer: true,
```

When I call the page target page directly I got the following console log message at the server console:

> WARN  asyncData

> WARN  fetch

But after a click to the button, which add something to the store and redirect to the target page, the console log messages will be displayed at the browser console. How do I get a redirect which is pre-rendered on the server side from nuxt?

Comment: Didn't get the question. Logs are there in both cases?

Comment: Yes. But when calling the second page directly from browser, the logs are on the server console (which I expect). When the first page redirect to the second the logs are only on the client console but I want to run the fetch/asyncdata on server side

Comment: This is how it works. On your initial load you have a serverside rendering of the page, from then on you have an app running on the client, so no server anymore: fetch and ayncData are both called once on the server and then when navigating (https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch/#when-to-use-fetch e.g.). This is expected behaviour. Could you describe again,what your desired behaviour looks like? Why does it matter if it is executed on the server or the client?

Answer (score 1):

SSR only happens for the *initial* request. Every further navigation via `$route.push`, `$router.replace` or `NuxtLink` will happen only client-side and "SPA-like". This combines the benefits of SSR for SEO + great initial performance with the capabilities of an SPA to avoid loading the whole content again and adding bits and pieces instead.

TL;DR: Intended behavior.

Another explanation during my talk here: https://vimeo.com/338836843#t=1000s

What you *can* do to force ssr (though you **usually should not**):

1. Use `window.location` or `$router.go(0)` to refresh the *current* page
2. Use `<a>` tags

**But be aware that this will remove a couple of perf benefits**.